# Update Ubuntu 14.04 Problem

Tags: 14.04, updates, chromium

Everytime I try to update my ubuntu, it returns this:
        W: Failed to search http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

```
    W: Failed to search http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

    W: Failed to search http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

    W: Failed to search http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

    E: Failed to download of some indexs. They were ignored or others have been used in the place
```

And also I can't install pygame...

Comment: Neither of those PPAs support 14.04. Remove them.

Answer (score 0):

This issue started coming up for me last week.  How I resolved it was removed the repositories from my list.

You can either do by going into software centre and unchecking the repositories in the list. Or remove them using the terminal window.

Comment: You realize that the question you're answering is already almost one year old and that it has been solved in the comments? Also, your answer does not really add any additional information to the comment.

Comment: @ByteCommander If and until this post is closed as a duplicate, isn't it a good thing that someone posted the comment as an answer? That way the original user has the ability (however unlikely) to accept it. Someone had to do it, and robobenklein or muru never followed through.